# Getting type mismatch error in replace function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

My vba code is to replace current time and date to 4_17_2014 8_09_00 PM format

But i am getting type mismatch error while running below VBA code

```
Function Current_Date_Time_Stamp()

Dim CurrTime As Date

CurrTime = Now
MsgBox Now
CurrTime = Replace(CurrTime, "-", "_")
MsgBox CurrTime
CurrTime = Replace(CurrTime, ":", "_")
Current_Date_Time_Stamp = CurrTime

End Function
```

Can anybody help me why i am getting error

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Replace operates on Strings, and you're giving it a Date.  Try looking at Format() if you want a specific representation of your Date value.

Comment: Tim Williams, I am getting error in 5th line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tim Williams mentioned in comments, `Replace` works only with *string* variables, but `CurrTime` is *date* (actually, date variables doesn't store *format* of date, but only date itself. Format when *displaying* date depends on regional settings and number format of your cell).

However you can use function with single line of code like this:

```
Function Current_Date_Time_Stamp()
    Current_Date_Time_Stamp = Format(Now, "mm_dd_yyyy h_mm_ss AM/PM;@")
End Function
```